# AngularJS unknown provider cookieReader

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to use AngularJS translations. The problem I encountered is that I'm getting `Unknown provider: $$cookieReaderProvider <- $$cookieReader <- $cookies <- $cookieStore <- $translateCookieStorage <- $translate <- $cookies` error when trying to use `$translateProvider.useCookieStorage();`

I've injected `ngCookies` as a dependency in my app:

```
var nfqApp = angular.module('myApp', ['postServices', 'angularFileUpload', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.date',
    'bootstrapLightbox', 'profileServices', 'ngRoute', 'angularMoment', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngCookies']);
```

I've also included following files related to translations and cookies in the following order:

- angular-translate.min.js
- angular-cookies.js
- angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat.js
- angular-translate-storage-cookie.js
- messageformat.js
- en.js
- lt.js

My app config (where I try to use cookieStorage:

```
myApp.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
$translateProvider.translations('lt', {
    "OTHER_LIKES" : "{peopleCount, plural, one {# kolega tai mėgsta} few {# kolegos tai mėgsta} other {# kolegų tai mėgsta}}",
    "YOU_AND_OTHERS_LIKES" : "{peopleCount, plural, one {Tu ir # kolega tai mėgsta} few {Tu ir # kolegos tai mėgsta} other {Tu ir # kolegų tai mėgsta}}",
    "YOU_LIKE" : "Tu mėgsti tai"
});

$translateProvider.translations('en', {
    "OTHER_LIKES" : "{peopleCount, plural, one {# colleague likes this} few {# colleagues likes this} other {# colleagues likes this}}",
    "YOU_AND_OTHERS_LIKES" : "{peopleCount, plural, one {You and # colleague likes this} few {You and # colleagues likes this} other {You and # colleagues likes this}}",
    "YOU_LIKE" : "You like this"
});

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('lt');

$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');

$translateProvider.addInterpolation('$translateMessageFormatInterpolation');

$translateProvider.useCookieStorage();
}]);
```

Comment: Just a guess but have you tried to put the ngCookies before pascalprecht.translate in the module definition ?

Comment: Tried that with no success.

Comment: Please provide a little bit more code, where did you inject your $cookie service? Show us that service/controller's definition and also tell us about your AngularJS version and angular-cookie version.

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to import my setup to another machine - I'm assuming it was an incompatible version problem since after I quit trying to do things through npm / bower and just brutecopied the packages, I got it working again.

Comment: @Rus Paul thanks for pointing me out. The problem was that I used different version of angular and angular-cookies

Comment: @Einius - I have this same problem. Which version of angular-cookies got this working for you?

Comment: @David Wadge - I believe angular.js and angular-cookies.js should be the same version. for me AngularJS v1.4.1 works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out that I was using angular-cookies.js designed for different version of angular. updating them both to the same version solved the problem. AngularJS v1.4.1 was used.

Answer (score 3):

I was using Ionic framework and angular.js in ionic.bundle.js was 1.3.6 but my angular-cookies version was 1.4.4
So I downgraded the version of angular-cookies and it worked out.

```
bower install angular-cookies#1.3.6
```