# AngularJS shows error for cookie injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/Demo1', {

          templateUrl: 'Staticloader.html',
          controller: 'appCtrl',
          resolve: {
              message: function(messageService){
                  return messageService.getMessage();
              }
          }     
      }).otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/Demo1'
      });          
}]);
```

This code gives me the following error:

> $injector: Unknown Provider Unknown provider: $$cookieReaderProvider
>   <- $$cookieReader <- $cookies <- $cookieStore <- $cookies

Comment: the code is not complete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS unknown provider cookieReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885568/angularjs-unknown-provider-cookiereader)